# Check if mail account is from sharedbox

Tags: c++, email, outlook, account, mailitem

I write code in Outlook plugin and I would like to identify when a mail is sent, if it's from a sharedbox mail or a userbox mail.

So I have the object of mail 'MailItem'
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa210946(v=office.11)

And I get the linked account with method 'SendUsingAccount' and I get object 'Account'
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._account?view=outlook-pia

But here i can't fine any method/property fto check if account is sharedbox or userbox

Has anyone an idea to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

That is a perfectly valid email address of type EX (as opposed to SMTP). Check the [MailItem.SenderEmailType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.senderemailtype) property. If it is "SMTP", use the SenderEmailAddress property. If it is "EX", use MailItem.Sender.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress. Be prepared to handle nulls/exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for answer,
In my  code, i get "EX" type but when I call "MailIteSender" property it returns NULL pointer

Comment: I have to say that i try chck if shardbox or userbox when mail is sending (not already sent)